# Most frequent value + number of time displayed in columns for each

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got the following order table:

> Client_name|Product 
>  Megane|#768_Samsung
>  Megane|#310_Apple
>   Megane|#659_Samsung
>  Victor|#890_Apple

I'd like to see for each client what's their most bought brand + the number of time they bought it.
So for this table, I'd like this result:

> Client_Name|Favourite_brand|Order_number
>  Megan|Samsung|2
>   Victor|Apple|1

So far this is the query I've built:

```
SELECT Client_name, brand 
  FROM (SELECT Client_name, brand, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client_name ORDER BY freq DESC) AS rn
          FROM (  SELECT Client_name, brand, COUNT('x') AS freq
                  FROM (SELECT Client_name, substring(Product,5) as brand
                        FROM Orders
                GROUP BY Client_name, brand) frequency) ranked) client
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

I am still struggling with removing the number before the brand name (ie #768 for instance) by using substring. I shows me an error message

> -ERROR:  column "frequency.Client_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

So I haven't started yet to think how to add the Order_number column

Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have your group by clause in the wrong spot.  Try moving it to after the 'frequency' but before the ')'

```
SELECT Client_name, brand 
  FROM (SELECT Client_name, brand, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client_name ORDER BY freq DESC) AS rn
          FROM (  SELECT Client_name, brand, COUNT('x') AS freq
                  FROM (SELECT Client_name, substring(Product,5) as brand
                        FROM Orders) frequency GROUP BY Client_name, brand) ranked) client
 WHERE rn = 1;
```